# InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime' from singleton '...IAuthentication' in Blazor

Tags: c#, singleton, blazor

I'm creating Blazor project that at first everything works fine until I need to inject `IJSRuntime`  into `cs` file.

```
Microsoft.JSInterop;
...
...

public BaseService(IJSRuntime jSRuntime)
{
}
```

`BaseService` is inherited in another service named `AuthenticationServices` which is also uses an Interface called `IAuthentication`. Thus

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

public class AuthenticationServices : BaseService, IAuthentication
{
    public AuthenticationServices(IJSRuntime jSRuntime) : base(jSRuntime)
    {
    }
}
```

My issue is in `Startup.cs`file which has this code

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthentication, AuthenticationServices>();
```

If I run the app it says,

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime' from singleton '...IAuthentication'
```

What does it mean? Am I doing it correctly that I only need something to add?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dependency injection in the Blazor has 3 different lifetime policies.

- Singleton
- Scope
- Transient

## Singleton

This means that any service of that type will have only one instance.

## Scope

This lifetime mean that for set of object created `scope` and within that scope will be just one instance. Usually in most scenarios, scope is created for processing User Session (Client-side Blazor) or User connection (Server-side Blazor). You can compare with scope per single HTTP request (ASP.NET).

## Transient

Object with this lifetime created each time they are requested. It's same to regular `new`.

## Lifetime consumption rules

Given the nature of these object lifetime policies, following rules for consuming services applies.

- `Transient` service can consume `Transient,` Scoped`and`Singleton` services.
- `Scoped` service can consume `Scoped` and `Singleton` services. But cannot consume `Transient` services.
- `Singleton` services can consume only `Singleton` services. But cannot consume `Transient` and `Scoped` services.

Service `IJSRuntime` registered inside Blazor as `Scoped` service, as such it can be used only by `Scoped` and `Transient` services.

So you either have to make `AuthenticationServices` the `Scoped` service, or get rid of `IJSRuntime` as constructor parameter.